# How to make Bitcoin-Qt client portable? (Windows)

Tags: bitcoin-core, portable

It is a nice project and all, but I think in 2013 it shouldn't be a challenge to save all of an application's files into its own folder (maybe even by default), so you can use it without installing/uninstalling.

I just don't have that much space on drive C. I use drive D for stuff. Is there a solution?

Google just brought me to [this discussion](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=105014.0) which lead to all the fancy alternatives to the original client. I just want to try original Bitcoin-Qt first.

Would no one be interested in a portable Bitcoin-Qt? It would be very useful in my opinion.

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Put the `bitcoin-qt.exe` binary in the folder
2. Create a `bitcoin.bat` file
3. Open the file with notepad
4. Add the following line: `bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir=.`
5. From now on you can start by double-clicking the bat

Comment: You can also create a shortcut, modify the shortcut properties, and add `-datadir=.` there.

Comment: This should work for any foobarCoin-Qt client.

Answer (score 1):

Make a folder called "data" in same folder as the application.

In a batch file, develop this code:

```
bitcoin-qt.exe -datadir=./data/
```